# List of small groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was checking this website https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_small_groups and wondering why don't we have $(\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z)^\times$ in the list of groups with 4 elements for example ?

$(\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z)^\times$ has 4 elements and is not in the list of groups with 4 elements and I do not know why ? Does it have to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z$ ?
Same thing for $(\mathbb Z/7 \mathbb Z)^\times$, $(\mathbb Z/9 \mathbb Z)^\times$ and $(\mathbb Z/14 \mathbb Z)^\times$ in the groups of 6 elements.

Comment: $(\mathbb Z/5 \mathbb Z)^\times$ **is** in the list, also known as $U(5)\cong C_4$, the cyclic group of order $4$. Writing it additively, it is $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$. In general $U(p)\cong C_{p-1}$ for primes $p$. Search for [multiplicative group of integers modulo $n$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n).

Comment: I only see $\mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z$ and Klein four-group in the list, it also says there exists only two groups of order 4.

Comment: See the duplicate! "Does it have to be isomorphic to $\mathbb Z/4 \mathbb Z$ ?" Yes, it has to be.

Comment: Ok I got it, I just saw what open problem said

Answer (score 0):

They list a representative up to isomorphism, and the group you are thinking of is already isomorphic to one of the ones on the list just represented differently. The cyclic group of order 4 in that particular case.

I will put the mapping to help:

$$1 -> 0$$
$$2 -> 1$$
$$4 -> 2$$
$$3 -> 3$$

Comment: Sorry for my imprecise language. I was speaking conversationally.